# Search XML file with partial text

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file and need to search it for text. The problem is the text I'm searching for is not the full string which is in the XML file. For example in the below example I have the name hill but not justin.

```
<people type="test">
   <category name="USA" id="1046" file_group="usa">
      <type date="24.12.2013" time="00:00" id="225100">
         <local name="justin hill" id="1185"/>
```

Is it possible to search the XML file in the way and get the associated ID of the user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look into [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) with [lxml](http://lxml.de/).